# How do I call a variable in another method

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to know how can i access the local variable `AverageBodylengths` in another methord call `jButton4ActionPerformed`

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
    float num3 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField5.getText());
    float num4 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField6.getText());
    float num5 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField7.getText());
    float num6 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField8.getText());
    float num7 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField9.getText());
    float num8 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField10.getText());
    float num9 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField11.getText());
    float num10 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField12.getText());
    float num11 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField13.getText());
    float num12 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField14.getText());

    float AverageBodylengths = (((num3) + (num4) + (num5) + (num6) + (num7) + (num8) + (num9) + (num10) + (num11) + (num12)) / 10);
    jLabel25.setText("" + AverageBodylengths + "mm");
}                                        

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{

}
```

Comment: If both methods are supposed to see it, then the variable belongs to the instance, not the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the variable global. Your code would look like this:

```
private float averageBodyLenght;
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


    float num3 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField5.getText());
    float num4 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField6.getText());
    float num5 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField7.getText());
    float num6 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField8.getText());
    float num7 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField9.getText());
    float num8 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField10.getText());
    float num9 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField11.getText());
    float num10 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField12.getText());
    float num11 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField13.getText());
    float num12 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField14.getText());

    averageBodylengths = (((num3) + (num4) + (num5) + (num6) + (num7) + (num8) + (num9) + (num10) + (num11) + (num12)) / 10);
    jLabel25.setText("" + AverageBodylengths + "mm");


}                                        

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
    //Do stuff with averageBodyLenght
}
```

Comment: I tried this. However in jButton4ActionPerformed, averageBodyLenght got 0 value.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `AverageBodylengths` literally does not exist when method `jButton3ActionPerformed` is not executing. That's the point of local variables. They are automatically created 'at the point of declaration' and destroyed when they go out of scope, in this case at the end of method execution.

If the question really means, how can you retrieve the last-computed value of `AverageBodylengths`, then the answer is to make a more permanent copy.  Make it an instance variable of the object (assuming these are object methods) or else global.

```
private float AverageBodylengths;

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    AverageBodylengths = …
}                                        

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
    … use AverageBodylengths …
}
```